# Angular Dart Components: cssUrl not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have come across this strange problem and it is driving me nuts. 
It looks like a bug, but I don't know if maybe I am doing someting wrong.

The CSS attached to a component via **cssUrl** doesn't work on **Internet Explorer**. 
If I add some content to the html template and I use classes from the CSS, those classes are not applied in IE. However, the same code works fine in Dartium, Chrome and Firefox.

---

I have created a sample project in github showing the error: 
https://github.com/gonzalopezzi/ie-angulardart-shadowdom-bug

The project has the following dependencies:

```dart
dependencies:
  browser: 0.10.0+2
  angular: 0.11.0
  shadow_dom: 0.10.0
```

(I have tried to avoid "any" but those are the latest versions of such packages)

I have a very simple component:

```dart
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

@Component(selector: 'internet-explorer-bug', 
        templateUrl:'internet-explorer-bug/internet-explorer-bug.html', 
        cssUrl:'internet-explorer-bug/internet-explorer-bug.css',
        useShadowDom: true,
        publishAs: 'cmp')
class InternetExplorerBug {
}
```

This is the css file (internet-explorer-bug.css):

```dart
.red-div {
  background-color: red;
}
```

And this is the template (internet-explorer-bug.html)

```dart
<div id="main-div">
  <div class="red-div">Red background?</div>
</div>
```

The component works properly in Dartium, Chrome and Firefox. It doesn't show the red background in Internet Explorer, though.

I have tested it in **Internet Explorer 10 and 11**. These are the results:

- The red **background** is **not displayed**
- The browser downloads the **css** file (I can see that in IE dev tools)
- If I inspect the **DOM**, I see a strange css attribute assigned to the div with the name **"background-color:red"** and **no value**:

  .red-div {
    background-color:red:   ;
  }

*I have posted the same question in the mailing list ([here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular-dart/J7XHDPgrSCQ)). If I somebody helps me there I will post the solution here too.*

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this line causes the problem

```dart
<script src="packages/shadow_dom/shadow_dom.min.js"></script>
```

This is deprecated. You should use

```dart
<script src="packages/web_components/platform.js"></script>
```

You need to change your pubspec.yaml too (`shadow_dom` to `web_components`)

Comment: Thank you, Günter. I think I also tried that, but I'll check it out later.

Comment: I have changed the shadow dom polyfill as you suggested, as it is explained here: http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shadow_dom). It is not working though. The result is the same as with shadow_dom.js. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I think you should create an issue then in the Angular.dart GitHub repo.